Processing a string or Environment variable as TRACEPARENT in Opentelemetry jenkins plugin
We are using jenkins with Opentelemetry plugin installation and OTLP endpoints configured properly to receive traces from pipeline runs.
Jenkins pipeline is called remotely(bitbucket webhook) with TRACEPARENT (ROOT span created outside Jenkins) as parameter(string),
Jenkins opentelemetry plugin always generates its own ROOT_SPAN and observability backend shows 2 different traces (with different TRACE ids) coming from BB and Jenkins.
I am  looking to view single trace showing lifespan of service request.
flowing through bitbucket-> Jenkins pipeline as single TRACE(multiple spans).
Workflow is:

A service request comes into Bitbucket source repo with a PR.
Bitbucket POST webhook calls a jenkins pipeline on remote host.
I send this TRACEPARENT as string parameter to jenkins.(build with parameters)
Jenkins generates its's own ROOT SPAN and sends traces to OTLP endpoint.

Objective: Jenkins opentelemetry to append its pipeline spans to TRACEPARENT received from Bitbucket webhook.
On jenkins, I tried:

Setting TRACEPARENT string as OS Environment variable via Groovy
Changing stage/step within jenkins pipeline to change env.TRACEPARENT to new value each time pipeline is called from webhook.

Observation: same as workflow step #4 above.
Expectation: jenkins plugin to honor TRACEPARENT from env variable OR build parameter as opentelemetry context.
So that:
Entire request of lifespan is shown properly with origin as BB span -> Jenkins pipelines spans (ALL having single TRACE_ID)
